# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using insert with KeyHolder

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

There is an example, which works in this version:

```
    String sql = "insert into album (name) VALUES (:name)";
    Object[] params = new Object[] { al.getName() };
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params);
```

And gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when in this version:

```
    KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    String sql = "insert into album (name) VALUES (:name)";
    Object[] params = new Object[] { al.getName() };
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params, holder);
```

Additional information:

```
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:db/springDB.db"></property>
    <property name="username" value=""></property>
    <property name="password" value=""></property>
</bean>
```

There is a stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.java:128)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setObject(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:388)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:402)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:166)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:66)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:47)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:914)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:980)
at com.user.impls.SQLiteDAO.insertAlbum(SQLiteDAO.java:214)
at com.user.app.Start.main(Start.java:34)
```

What is wrong here? Seems like there is no error. The first version inserts data and creates an id. But the second gives error. Thank you

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yes, sure, I will edit the question and add the stack trace

Comment: Which version of Spring and which version sqlite are you using? Also, please post a [mcve]. It is unclear what type `jdbcTemplate` is, `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, although the stacktrace suggests `JdbcTemplate`; which may be the problem. Try using `?` instead of `:name`

Comment: Spring version 4.0.3 and SqLite version 3.24.0. All right, I have added more information.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you mentioned, that there may be a problem with the JdbcTemplate, I tried NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and it worked. Thank you, so this is solved. I don't know how to vote comment as solution.

Comment: Consider posting your own solution as an answer. I was just guessing and didn't have time to test anything to write a real answer, so I posted the comment as a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate instead of JdbcTemplate, as [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) suggested, solves the problem.